# Overpopulated apartment

Tags: discrete-mathematics, invariance

$119$ people live in a building with $120$ apartments. An apartment is called overpopulated if there are more than $15$ people living in it. Each day the tenants of some overpopulated apartment have a quarrel and they all move to different apartments in the same building. Is it true that eventually none of the apartments will be overpopulated?

Attempts and observations:

- If we organize the building into a $15\times 8$ grid with $8$ floors, after a quarrel at least $2$ of new floors(floors other than the floor on which the quarrel happened) occupy $1$ more tenants each(floors might be same)
- If an apartment is called overpopulated if there are more than $14$ people in it, then the answer is no
- If we prove that this process terminate, then we are done

Comment: how are all the 119 people distributed amongst the 120 apartments to begin with? if there is a quarrel do the 15 people relocate to 15 new different apartments?

Comment: We don’t know the distribution. There is a quarrel only with 16 or more people in which case they do relocated to new different appartment

Comment: All of them move out of the appartment

Comment: Not just the extra person

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118586/discussion-between-saket-yagay-and-no-lemon-no-melon).

Comment: Maybe this example is simpler: say you have two apartments A and B. A has 16 people, quarrel breaks out, all of them move to B. Next day all of them move to A. Next day to B, next day... And so on, and so on, an infinite loop. And no overpopulation threshold changes that.

Comment: Or perhaps they move randomly and this is a question about the expected number of days until no apartment is overpopulated? But then it will work for any overpopulation threshold because there are more apartments than tenants.

Comment: It is given that they all move to distinct apartments

Comment: For eg, 2 people from overpopulated apartment X can’t move to same apartment just yet

Comment: @saketyagay $7$ apartements with $15$ people plus $1$ apartement with $14$ people is a stationary situation. There are many others, until each person is in one apartment and 1 is empty. If one of these situation is reached the problem terminates. Am I right?

Comment: @raffaele yes you are

Answer (score 1):

To try and prove that it is false would entail beginning from an overpopulated apartment, dispersing the inhabitants to different apartments  and getting another overpopulated apartment, and thus dispersing the inhabitants can cause the population of an apartment to increase by one for each abandoned apartment.

Say, you wanted a sequence of overpopulated apartments with $n_i$ people living in each one,
$$ n_i \geq 16 ,1 \leq i \leq m+1.$$

Beginning from $n_1$, $n_1$ people are dispersed to $n_1$ different apartments, if you want an apartment next with $n_2$ people in it, you would of needed to have an apartment with at least $n_2 -1$ people in it at first go. And then an apartment with at least $n_3 -2$ people in it at first go... and so on and so on.

Thus in general there must be $n_1 + n_2 -1 + n_3 -2 + ... =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m+1} n_i - \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m}i \geq 16(m+1)-\frac{m(m+1)}{2}= 136> 119$ for $m=16$, since an apartment cannot have negative people in it. Thus if you wanted a sequence other than $16,16,16,...$ you would need even more people.